# f# class constructor formatting

Tags: json, visual-studio, constructor, f#

I am creating a program that takes an email and converts it into json.  In the interest of learning functional languages I thought it would be a good opportunity to learn F#.  So first off I want a message class that can then easily be serialized into json.  This class will have some members that can be null.  Because of these optional parameters I am using the following format

```
type Email(from:string, recipient:string, ?cc:string .........) =
    member x.From = from
    member x.Recipient = recipient.....
```

This class actually has a lot of members as I want to store every piece of information that an email could have.  What happens is if I try to format the constructor myself by splitting it onto multiple lines I get warnings.  How do people make such a gigantic constructor look good in f#?  Is there a better way to do this?

On a similar note, I'm not finding visual studio very helpful for f#, what are other people using to code?  I think there is a mode for emacs for example...

Comment: Why do you think Visual Studio isn't helpful for F#? It is exactly one reason making F# more appealing than other functional programming languages - it has *good tooling support*.

Comment: Most people writing F# are using Visual Studio -- what is it that you're not finding helpful? In any case, the main alternatives are MonoDevelop and emacs, and there are partially-complete plugins for TextMate and Sublime Text.

Comment: Well, I'm a complete beginner with F# but so far it just feels like it's not helping me.  I can't explain it and hopefully as I understand more I will realise that it is helping.

Comment: Make sure if you do code in something besides VS that you have the editor convert tabs to spaces.  Tabs make things line up nicely but the F# compiler will balk at them.  Not to toot my own horn but I did a writeup on using F# with Sublime Text a ways back: http://onorioc.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/configuring-sublime-text-2-to-work-with-fsharp/

Answer (score 3):

There should not be any warnings if all "newlined" parameters start at the same column. For example:

```
type Email(from:string, recipient:string,
           ?cc:string) =
    member x.From = from
    member x.Recipient = recipient
```

(I personally enjoy using Visual Studio for F#. I doubt there is an IDE with more complete support.)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to creating constructor that takes *all* properties as parameters, you can also create an object with mutable properties and then specify only those that you want to set in the construction:

```
type Email(from:string, recipient:string) =
  member val From = from with get, set
  member val Recipient = recipient with get, set
  member val Cc = "" with get, set
  member val Bcc = "" with get, set

let eml = Email("me@me.com", "you@you.com", Cc="she@she.net")
```

This is using a new `member val` feature of F# 3.0. Writing the same in F# 2.0 would be pretty annoying, because you'd have to define getter and setter by hand.

Comment: Hmm, this looks great at first sight but if I want my class to be immutable this won't be right will it?